# How to modify json file with PHP

Tags: php, json

I need to modify the json but only inside t03_action -> effect property, but inside that is another json object. How can i change the data inside that one?
I already can change the data inside t05_file like this

```
    for($i = 0; $i < $count_data; $i++){
        $json_data[t05_file][data][$i][path] = "../uploads/".$id."/";
    }
    $newJsonString = json_encode($json_data);
    file_put_contents('data/AA/view_data.json', $newJsonString);
```

Here is my code for change the t03_action data inside json

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count_data_action; $i++){
   $path_data_action =  $json_data[t03_action][data][$i][effect_property];
   $effectPropertyArray = json_decode($path_data_action,true);
    if(isset($effectPropertyArray[propTo]['source_path'])) {
        $action_data = $effectPropertyArray[propTo]["source_path"]. $effectPropertyArray[propTo]["source_file"];
        $list_action_files[] = $action_data;
        $file_action_name[]=  $effectPropertyArray[propTo]["source_file"];
    }
 $effectPropertyArray[propTo]["source_path"] = "../uploads/".$id."/";
}
$newJsonActionString = json_encode($effectPropertyArray);
file_put_contents('data/AA/view_data.json', $newJsonActionString);
```

But when i check my json file, it only have the $effectPropertyArray, how to do this?

Comment: 1. convert json to Object: `json_decode($json_string);` 2. change value/property of your object. 3. convert back to json: `json_encode($object);`

Comment: you need to convert it into array or object and change it. after that, encode it to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, i made a mistake with my code

Here is the working code

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count_data_action; $i++){
    $path_data_action =  $json_data[t03_action][data][$i][effect_property];
    $effectPropertyArray = json_decode($path_data_action,true);
        if(isset($effectPropertyArray[propTo]['source_path'])) {
            $action_data = $effectPropertyArray[propTo]["source_path"]. $effectPropertyArray[propTo]["source_file"];
            $list_action_files[] = $action_data;
            $file_action_name[]=  $effectPropertyArray[propTo]["source_file"];
        }
     $effectPropertyArray[propTo]["source_path"] = "../uploads/".$id."/";
     //HERE IS THE MISSING PART
       $json_data[t03_action][data][$i][effect_property] =json_encode($effectPropertyArray);
     }

    $newJsonActionString = json_encode($json_data);
    file_put_contents('data/AA/view_data.json', $newJsonActionString);
```

So, after you finish change the desire object, just put it back into the decoded json, then just encode and use file_put_contents to update it.

Hope it help someone else ^^